# Starting "Identify and Repair network problems" Network troubleshooter from commandline

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to integrate the initiation of this troubleshooter into a python script.

I've found https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattbie/2010/11/09/running-a-troubleshooter-from-the-command-line/ which lists various commands to open different Troubleshooters but the "Identify and Repair Network Problems" is nowhere to be found.

When there's a problem with the internet connection, clicking on the ethernet icon in the system tray opens this troubleshooter or you could open the same by searching "Identify and Repair Network Problems" in the search box of taskbar.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that there's a command for that. You can access this through control panel though in the Network and Sharing Centre.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to integrate this functionality in to a python program. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the "Identify and Repair Network Problems" troubleshooter using this command line:

```
msdt -skip TRUE -path C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsConnectivity
```

Where `-skip TRUE` allows you to skip the first screen and go straight into the diagnostics.

or this one:

```
rundll32.exe,C:\Windows\system32\Rundll32.exe ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident
```

If you start the "Identify and Repair Network Problems" troubleshooter and then run `wmic process where "caption='rundll32.exe' or caption='msdt.exe'" get /format:csv`, you will notice something like the following:

```
Caption,CommandLine,ParentProcessId,ProcessId
rundll32.exe,C:\Windows\system32\Rundll32.exe ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident,11088,10272
msdt.exe, -skip TRUE -path C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\networking -af C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\NDFBC7D.tmp -ep NetworkDiagnosticsConnectivity,10272,10528
```

Based on that, clicking on the troubleshooter shortcut runs `C:\Windows\system32\Rundll32.exe ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident`, which starts `msdt.exe` with an unusual command line that doesn't contain `msdt.exe`.

This command-line can't be run by itself. The `NDFBC7D.tmp` file seems to be created by the `rundll32.exe` process, so removing the `-af` switch solves that issue and allows you to run the troubleshooter without `rundll32.exe`.